# Java Looping year from now to back

Tags: java, for-loop

I try to make looping with format Time/Date, but i have stuck to makeit

So i want to loop year, from now(2019 to 5 years before).

```
Date d = new Date();
long tahun = d.getYear();
long hitung = tahun - 5;

for (long i = tahun; i >= hitung; i--) {
 d = new Date(tahun);
 d.getYear()
}
```

Actualy i expect output like this:
2019
2018
2017
2016
2015
2014

Comment: What argument does the `long` constructor for `Date` take? Hint: it isn't the year.

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalDate`, makes it far easier.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ehhh...thanks, u right, now my code solve :D

Comment: if you just want to print the years then why not directly print ```i```?

Comment: getYear() is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int yearNow = date.getYear();
int minYear = yearNow - 5;

while(yearNow >= minYear) {
    System.out.println(yearNow--);
}
```

Comment: @CarboniBag choose the best answer to guide others.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of `Date#getYear()`:

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

So you'd have to add `1900` to get the correct year out (Next to the flaw @BorisTheSpider pointed out in his comment). But there is a better way, using the new `java.time` api which replaces the old `Date` api:

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(d.getYear());
    d = d.minusYears(1);
}
```

Which prints:

```
2019
2018
2017
2016
2015
2014
```

Comment: If you just want to print the years using a time API is surely overkill. That would be my first point of clarification - are the dates actually needed, or just the year?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I assume the example given by OP is simplified. But else, yeah you're right. If its just printing the year then `System.currentTimeMillis() / 31536000000L + 1970` could be used, its a crude approach, but will probably work most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Using Calendar :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();   
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Logic is low...
I just understood now, this just be simple like this:

```
    int tahun = 2019;
    int hitung = tahun - 5;

    for (int i = tahun; i >= hitung; i--) {
        system.out.println(i)
    }
```

Now i just need to get Years from Date.utils